# Is it bad practice to define a "custom" HTML tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a custom HTML tag in my code (`<include>`). Is this bad practice and if so what should it be replaced with?

It seems to me that it adds readability to the code by having the meaning in the tag name instead of a `<div class="include">`.

Comment: The main problem with custom elements is what happens if they get added to the standard or a browser in the future, then you'll have a conflict.

Comment: You’re supposed to add a prefix. That takes care of future conflicts. See answer below

Comment: Custom HTML tags are supposed to contain at least one hyphen to be valid HTML. e.g. `<my-include></my-include>`. Sources: https://matthewjamestaylor.com/custom-tags#custom-tag-naming-rules,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements#name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating custom HTML tags are perfectly fine nowadays, however, you need to know how to properly create them, for a better browser support. Make sure they have a semantic "meaning", or "role" for better readability and accessibility. It is great when working with web components.

Here is a good article about creating custom html elements:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/introduction-to-custom-elements/

Answer (score 32):

Custom HTML tags are misunderstood and should actually be considered *best-practice*.

Browsers will download and parse markup that has custom or *unknown* tags with no issue at all. Browsers will also style them with the CSS rules you provide. Here's an example:

**HTML**

`<my-alert status="success">Hello custom tags!</my-alert>`

**CSS**

```
my-alert[status="success"] { 
  color: white;
  background-color: green; 
}
```

The front-end world went crazy for classes (partly because old browsers didn't handle unknown tags well*), so the above is normally done like:

**HTML**

`<div class="alert alert-success">Hello custom tags!</div>`

**CSS**

```
.alert.alert-success { 
  color: white;
  background-color: green; 
}
```

Both work exactly the same, but the custom tag design is aligned with the Custom Elements spec, uses familiar HTML constructs (tag, attributes, nesting), and prepares this little static Alert to evolve into a true Custom Element or Web Component in a *standards-based backwards-compatible way.* I think the custom tag code looks way better than a non-semantic tag with a bunch of classes too.

You can do a lot with custom tags while still meeting all the requirements of good HTML. This chip element with an icon, for example, offers a nice API and has good semantics with just using CSS (imagine a list of filters for hotel amenities):

```html
<x-chip role="button" aria-pressed="true" title="Breakfast" aria-label="Breakfast">
  <x-icon name="mug"></x-icon>
</x-chip>
<x-chip role="button" aria-pressed="false" title="Wifi" aria-label="Wifi">
  <x-icon name="wifi"></x-icon>
</x-chip>
```

I wrote the **TAC CSS methodology** for creating custom HTML that supports building simple CSS components all the way to full-blown Web Components seamlessly:
https://jordanbrennan.hashnode.dev/tac-a-new-css-methodology

*The old HTML 2.0 spec wasn't very fault-tolerant when it came to unknown tags, but thankfully that changed in HTML 4.01:

> to facilitate experimentation and interoperability between implementations of various versions of HTML, we recommend the following behavior:
>
> If a user agent encounters an element it does not recognize, it should try to render the element's content.
> If a user agent encounters an attribute it does not recognize, it should ignore the entire attribute specification (i.e., the attribute and its value).
> If a user agent encounters an attribute value it doesn't recognize, it should use the default attribute value.
> If it encounters an undeclared entity, the entity should be treated as character data.

For reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-invalid-docs

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize I was so behind the times on custom tags. Great answer and great linked article - I love the custom tag + attribute approach versus a list of classes

Comment: Is `status` a valid attribute? I thought you had to use the data prefix, eg `data-status`

Comment: It’s not a standard attribute, but it is valid markup. And there is no risk of conflict in the future if you use a custom prefixed tag.

Comment: As far as I know, the minus sign is not allowed in tags. Some browsers might still accept it though.

Comment: Quote: "Tags contain a tag name, giving the element's name. HTML elements all have names that only use characters in the range U+0030 DIGIT ZERO (0) to U+0039 DIGIT NINE (9), U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A to U+007A LATIN SMALL LETTER Z, and U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to U+005A LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z. In the HTML syntax, tag names, even those for foreign elements, may be written with any mix of lower- and uppercase letters that, when converted to all-lowercase, matches the element's tag name; tag names are case-insensitive. "
https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#elements-0

Comment: @BluE custom tags can and should follow the rules for Custom Elements, which is to use a dash in the tag name.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed custom tags would be a subset of html tags. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: the "in-depth explanation" blog link is 404 @jordanfb

Comment: Your linked article is gone (404), but I found it in the web archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20230131180148/https://dev.to/jfbrennan/custom-html-tags-4788

Comment: Fixed link to point to a better write up

Comment: I would strongly disagree with the sentiment that using custom elements is "best practice"—especially whenever there's an equivalent standard element. They are 100% fine if approached carefully, but it should be noted that custom elements have no inherent semantics and can create major accessibility issues if not handled correctly. This answer should be updated to note that.

Comment: If the Custom Elements API isn’t best practice for creating custom HTML, what is?

Comment: @jordanfb If that's what you intended to say, please edit the answer. As it stands, the answer states that the use of custom HTML tags should be considered best practice — _not_ that the Custom Elements API is the best practice for creating custom elements. You actually haven't mentioned _anything_ about using the API, which requires custom elements to be registered with JS. A novice reading this answer would come away thinking that it's best practice to make up your own elements without registering them or providing any semantic meaning.

Comment: @Sean The accepted answer provides a link to a Custom Elements intro. My answer references Custom Elements twice and Web Components twice. And, in my opinion, defining a custom hyphenated HTML tag with custom attributes has all the semantics a boilerplate div with classes is missing. I believe this should be considered best-practice. If/when it needs JS, then it can become a "real" Custom Element, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @jordanfb When I say "semantics" I'm not talking about subjective developer readability, but instead the very [objective set of meanings inherent in standard HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html) and the supplemental ARIA spec. I worry that without explicit mention that semantics should be considered and accounted for, this answer contributes to custom elements being misunderstood and misapplied.

Comment: Added example with ARIA usage

Comment: "*And there is no risk of conflict in the future if you use a custom prefixed tag.*" Sorry, but this is entirely wrong. You were probably assuming that attributes are never defined on the whole `HTMLElement` interface, or even `Element`, a lot of them are, and if somehow you write a library with enough traction that does use an attribute that would have made sense for the standards API, then said standards won't be able to use the name because every website using your lib will be broken. Please always use `data-` attributes for your custom attributes.

Comment: @Kaiido the CSS for `status` only applies to alert elements, so no risk of conflict, not even if HTML defined a global status attribute (CSS is still safe). The risk _may_ come if this was a Custom Element with _JavaScript_ managing `status` behavior and then HTML introduced a  _global_ `status` attribute  _with_ conflicting behavior. None of that is relevant to my example though. Defining `data-` attributes is a bad design because those are for  _consumers_ of elements, not  _authors_ (i.e. a developer publishing a Custom Element or the HTML spec folks).

Comment: There is still a risk of conflict. Take for instance the `popover` attribute that got added recently, it's now defined by the specs that elements with this attribute will have a `display:none` rule applied to them. So every website that used an unprefixed `popover` attribute, even on custom elements, will now be potentially broken.

Comment: @Kaiido I understand. This has been a question for WHATWG since 2017. But there's 7+ yrs of Custom Elements with these custom attributes in production now. Chrome says 20% of websites - millions of websites - use CE. CE libs like Material, Carbon, and many others do this. Popular non-CE libs do it. This ship set sail years ago. Is it absolutely perfect? No, but it has been working for millions of websites for many years. WHATWG may yet step in... 

FWIW a CE with `popover` won't be hidden because its CSS overrides user agent styles.

Comment: "FWIW a CE with popover won't be hidden because its CSS overrides user agent styles." For this you'd need to write the CSS that would override the `display` property, if the default inline is fine to the authors why would they set it explicitly? You didn't in your example. And that's just one of the cases where this can become problematic. Yes there are bad stuff on the web so what? Are we supposed to say it's fine to do so just because some didn't care or weren't aware?

Comment: Also, most of the time the non `data-` attributes that are used on CE are attributes that already exist (or did exist) on other elements, e.g `size`, or `color`, and these are fine to be reused on CE because we won't be able to reuse them earlier in the prototype chain anyway.

Comment: We must not abuse `data-` attributes. They are not relevant to CE. "Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data...private to the page or application." A website owner should be free to add any data attr to a native element or CE and access it via `dataset` with JS w/o ever conflicting with an element's own attrs. So then, a CE defines its own custom attrs (there 1000's of examples) and it may watch these change internally with `observedAttributes` and `attributeChangedCallback` and reflect them as properties with a getter/setter. These attrs are completely unrelated to data attrs.

Comment: Defining custom attributes is not "bad stuff" done by people who "don't care" or "weren't aware." These two examples are from the official Custom Elements spec: `<flag-icon country="nl"></flag-icon>` and `<img-viewer filter="Kelvin">...</img-viewer>`. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

It's important to adhere to certain standards for your web page to be effectively indexed by Google, especially when using custom HTML tags. This topic has been discussed in depth here - [Google Seo and HTML Custom Tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/169543610/google-seo-and-html-custom-tags?hl=en)

Additionally, a helpful post outlining essential guidelines is available:
[18 Things to know before using Custom HTML Tags](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/custom-tags) These guidelines include naming conventions for HTML tags (avoiding capital letters at the start) and not using underscores as we do with variable naming.

While custom HTML tags can be useful, I would recommend caution before deploying them in a production environment. It's crucial to ensure their wide acceptance and compatibility to maintain the effectiveness and reach of your website.

Comment: There's no need for caution. They are a web standard with 100% browser support - we're supposed to be using them ;)